# How to efficiently get the values from a HashMap with a static class?

Tags: java, hashmap, static-class

I have a class with a `HashMap<k,v>`.
The type of the values of this `HashMap` is a static class which has two different objects as attributes. i.e.,

```
   public class Example {
      private HashMap<String, StaticClassExample> map;
      private static class StaticClassExample {
           private Object1 o1;
           private Object2 o2;
           //...   
      }
      //...
   }
```

And my question is how can I do this operation efficiently:

```
   public List<Object1> getAllObject1() {}
```

I know that I can do: `map.values()` and then iterate the values collection and get Object1 from each StaticClassExample, but this wouldn't be efficient. 
It's possible what I ask or I must create another hashmap for my purpose?

Comment: What does it being a static class have to do with anything? Surely the only thing that's relevant is you want a projection from the map values. Frankly it's going to be hard to make this very efficient (no iteration) without also making it pretty brittle... do you definitely need a `List<Object1>` instead of just an `Iterable<Object1>`?

Comment: Do you really need a `List`? Otherwise, you could make it lazy...

Comment: Yes, I need a List with the all Object1 from the hashmap. So I guess that I would have to choice another representation...

Comment: Why do you believe that building a List from map.values() is inefficient? Have you profiled your program and determined that it takes 90% of the total execution time? If you haven't, then you're wasting your time worrying about meaningless things.

Comment: And why do you need a List? Are you passing it to some third-party library? If not, then change your code to take a `Collection`, and pass the values() result to it.

Comment: I don't care about the execute time, but the efficiency must be O(1) or O(log n).

Comment: Thank you all for the comments, I decided to change/complete the representation of the class. I thought there might be a method to do what I wanted, but I see that it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind some memory overhead, you could keep a separate list with the o1-values:

```
public class HashMapList
{
    private HashMap<String, StaticClassExample> map = new HashMap<String, HashMapList.StaticClassExample>();

    private List<Object> o1List = new LinkedList<Object>();

    public static class StaticClassExample
    {
        private Object o1;
        private Object o2;
    }

    public void addStaticClassExample(String key, StaticClassExample example)
    {
        StaticClassExample oldVal = map.put(key, example);
        if(oldVal != null)
        {
            o1List.remove(oldVal.o1);
        }
        o1List.add(example.o1);
    }

    public StaticClassExample getStaticClassExampleByKey(String key)
    {
        return map.get(key);
    }

    public void removeStaticClassExampleByKey(String key)
    {
        StaticClassExample removed = map.remove(key);
        if(removed != null)
        {
            o1List.remove(removed.o1);
        }
    }

    public List<Object> getAllObject1()
    {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(o1List);
    }   

}
```

Of course, this requires you to encapsule the HashMap inside the class and never give a straight access to it, because then someone using the class could modify the HashMap directly, and the List would no longer be in sync with the Map. Note that `getAllObject1` returns an unmodifiable view of the internal list, so it can't be modified from outside of the class.

Comment: Yes, as I guessed, I would have to create a more complete representation. Ty.